# CSS not loading in Safari

Tags: javascript, css, safari

I was working on a Discord Tutorial Site (http://elix.sap.md/elix/forgive),
where I had an external CSS file. In Chrome everything worked fine Now when I tried it on Safari, the CSS settings were gone. Where in Chrome you were able to see colorful columns, in Safari only the text.
I have no idea what happened.

This is how it looks in Chrome:
[image]

And this is how it looks on Safari:
[image]

```css
.uber {
  text-align: center;
}

.column {
  width: calc(50% - 1px);
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
}

.colleft {
  border-right: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgb(250, 250, 250)
}
```

```html
<h1 class="uber">Opilite's Discord Tutorial</h1>
<h2 class="uber">Lernen, wie man mit Discord umgeht; auch in unser Klassenserver</h2>
<div class="column colleft">
  <h2 class="uber">Basiswissen</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>Wie beginnt man mit Discord?</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="column">
  <h2 class="uber">Unser Server</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>Was musst du im unserem Server wissen?</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Can someone help me?
Thanks in advance,
Opilite

Comment: Try this: https://autoprefixer.github.io/ if that doesn't work we are not able to help without seeing into your code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Should I upload the HTML too?

Answer (score 1):

I have prefixed your CSS using the tool listed below.

After searching through inspect element I've noticed that your styles.css is linked incorrectly.
[image]

Try to make sure your `<link>` in the header points to the right address. If you've done this,

EDIT: I have found out the working path for your css link. See the following screenshot.
[image]

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="forgive/styles.css">
```

If you still can't see the style, paste the following CSS formated with [autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/) in the styles.css file to see the results.

```
/*
* Prefixed by https://autoprefixer.github.io
* PostCSS: v8.4.14,
* Autoprefixer: v10.4.7
* Browsers: last 22 version
*/

.uber {
  text-align: center;
}

.column {
  width: -webkit-calc(50% - 1px);
  width: calc(50% - 1px);
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
}

.colleft {
  border-right: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgb(250, 250, 250)
}
```

[image]

Comment: I have edited it. Now it should work

Comment: Your styles.css file is empty.

Comment: Huh? In safari? Or in chrome too?

Comment: Both, Edited answer

Comment: Still doesn’t work

Comment: What is your file structure. Your CSS is not linked.

Comment: Check edit, change your `<link>` to that and the CSS will work

Comment: Still doesn't work

Comment: Because you still havent implemented the fix I posted...

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="forgive/styles.css">` in the HTML `<head>`

Comment: but if I implement your fix then the CSS gets lost on Chrome

Comment: Then in that case add both

Answer (score -1):

sometimes older versions of some browsers doesn't support more advanced features so either update your browser or write code the way, that your browser supports it.

doing this will solve all the problems.

Comment: I don't think my Safari is old and my code isn't advanced either ... But how do I write the code for a older version?@Babulo

Comment: -moz-border-right: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);  and -moz-background-color: rgb(250, 250, 250)  like this.